# How to assign output of cat to an object?

Tags: r, variable-assignment

How would it be possible in the example below to skip the step of writing to file "test.txt", i.e. assign the cat-result to an object, and still achieve the same end result?

I thought I'd include the full example to give background to my problem.

```
test <- c("V 1", "x", "1 2 3", "y", "3 5 8", "V 2", "x", "y", "V 3", "y", "7 2 1", "V 4", "x", "9 3 7", "y")

# Write selection to file
cat(test, "\n", file="test.txt")
test2 <- readLines("test.txt")
test3 <- strsplit(test2, "V ")[[1]][-1]

# Find results
x <- gsub("([0-9]) (?:x )?([0-9] [0-9] [0-9])?.*", "\\1 \\2 ", test3, perl = TRUE)
y <- gsub("([0-9]).* y ?([0-9] [0-9] [0-9])?.*", "\\1 \\2 ", test3, perl = TRUE)

# Eliminate tests with no results
x1 <- x[regexpr("[0-9] ([^0-9]).*", x) == -1]
y1 <- y[regexpr("[0-9] ([^0-9]).*", y) == -1]

# Dataframe of results
xdf1 <- read.table(textConnection(x1), col.names=c("id","x1","x2","x3"))
ydf1 <- read.table(textConnection(y1), col.names=c("id","y1","y2","y3"))
closeAllConnections()

# Dataframe of tests with no results
x2 <- x[regexpr("[0-9] ([^0-9]).*", x) == 1]
y2 <- y[regexpr("[0-9] ([^0-9]).*", y) == 1]

df1 <- as.integer(x2[x2 == y2])
df1 <- data.frame(id = df1)

# Merge dataframes
results <- merge(xdf1, ydf1, all = TRUE)
results <- merge(results, df1, all = TRUE)
results
```

Results in:

```
  id x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
1  1  1  2  3  3  5  8
2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3  3 NA NA NA  7  2  1
4  4  9  3  7 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of `cat`ing to a file, why not use the `paste` command to generate a string instead?

```
> paste(test, collapse="\n")
[1] "V 1\nx\n1 2 3\ny\n3 5 8\nV 2\nx\ny\nV 3\ny\n7 2 1\nV 4\nx\n9 3 7\ny"
```

Now instead of doing a `cat` then `readlines` you can just pass this string directly into `strsplit`.

Answer (score 56):

As a more general solution, you can use the capture output function. It results in a character vector with elements corresponding to each line of the output.

your example:

```
test2<-capture.output(cat(test))
```

here is a multi-line example:

```
> out<-capture.output(summary(lm(hwy~cyl*drv,data=mpg)))
> out
 [1] ""                                                               
 [2] "Call:"                                                          
 [3] "lm(formula = hwy ~ cyl * drv, data = mpg)"                      
 [4] ""                                                               
 [5] "Residuals:"                                                     
 [6] "    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max "                       
 [7] "-8.3315 -1.4139 -0.1382  1.6479 13.5861 "                       
 [8] ""                                                               
 [9] "Coefficients:"                                                  
[10] "            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    "           
[11] "(Intercept)  32.1776     1.2410  25.930  < 2e-16 ***"           
[12] "cyl          -2.0049     0.1859 -10.788  < 2e-16 ***"           
[13] "drvf          8.4009     1.8965   4.430 1.47e-05 ***"           
[14] "drvr          8.2509     6.4243   1.284    0.200    "           
[15] "cyl:drvf     -0.5362     0.3422  -1.567    0.119    "           
[16] "cyl:drvr     -0.5248     0.8379  -0.626    0.532    "           
[17] "---"                                                            
[18] "Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 "
[19] ""                                                               
[20] "Residual standard error: 2.995 on 228 degrees of freedom"       
[21] "Multiple R-squared: 0.7524,\tAdjusted R-squared: 0.747 "         
[22] "F-statistic: 138.6 on 5 and 228 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16 "       
[23] ""
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
> f <- textConnection("test3", "w")
> cat(test, "\n", file=f)
> test3
[1] "V 1 x 1 2 3 y 3 5 8 V 2 x y V 3 y 7 2 1 V 4 x 9 3 7 y "
> close(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the assign statement which allows you to build a name and set an object to it. Very useful if you want to iterate a bunch of tests and name them with dynamic values.

assign("mary", paste(test,sep= "\n"))

will assign the paste statement to mary. However say you were running a bunch of regressions and wanted your regression objects named by predictor. You could do something like

```
assign(paste("myRegression",names(dataframe)[2],sep=""), lm(dataframe$response~dataframe[,2]))
```

which would give you the object

myRegressionPredictorName as you linear model.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following codes:

`writeLines(capture.out((summary(lm(hwy~cyl*drv,data=mpg)),con="summary.txt",sep="\n")`

Then you can open the txt file "summary.txt" to see your results.