# What are the differences between concatenating strings with cat() and paste()?

Tags: r, character, string-concatenation, r-faq

What are the differences between concatenating strings with `cat` and `paste`?

In particular, I have the following questions.

1. Why does R **not** use the double quote (`"`) when it prints the results of calling `cat` (but it uses quotes when using `paste`)?

   ```
   > cat("test")
   test
   > paste("test")
   [1] "test"
   ```
2. Why do the functions `length` and `mode`, which are functions available for almost all objects in R, **not** "work" on `cat`?

   ```
   > length(cat("test"))
   test[1] 0
   > mode(cat("test"))
   test[1] "NULL"
   ```
3. Why do C-style escape sequences work with `cat`, but **not** with `paste`?

   ```
   > cat("1)Line1\n 2)Line2\n 3)Line3")
   1)Line1
    2)Line2
    3)Line3
   > paste("1)Line1\n 2)Line2\n 3)Line3")
   [1] "1)Line1\n 2)Line2\n 3)Line3"
   ```
4. Why doesn't R's recycling rule work with `cat`?

   ```
   > cat("Grade", c(2, 3, 4, 5))
   Grade 2 3 4 5
   > paste("Grade", c(2, 3, 4, 5))
   [1] "Grade 2" "Grade 3" "Grade 4" "Grade 5"
   ```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

***`cat` and `paste` are to be used in very different situations**.*

---

### `paste` is not `print`

When you `paste` something and don't assign it to anything, it becomes a `character` variable that is `print`-ed using `print.default`, the default method for `character`, hence the quotes, etc. You can look at the help for `print.default` for understanding how to modify what the output looks like.

- `print.default` will not evaluate escape characters such as `\n` within a character string.

Look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1405571/3924118) for how to capture the output from `cat`.

---

Quoting from the easy to read  help for `cat` (`?cat`)

> ### Concatenate and Print
>
> #### Description
>
> Outputs the objects, concatenating the representations. `cat` performs
>   much less conversion than `print`.
>
> ...
>
> #### Details
>
> `cat` is useful for producing output in user-defined functions. It
>   converts its arguments to `character` vectors, concatenates them to a
>   single `character` vector, appends the given `sep= string(s)` to each
>   element and then outputs them.
>
> #### Value
>
> None (invisible `NULL`).

`cat` **will not return anything**, it will just output to the console or another connection.

Thus, if you try to run `length(cat('x'))` or `mode(cat('x'))`, you are running `mode(NULL)` or `length(NULL)`, which will return `NULL`.

---

The help for paste is equally helpful and descriptive

> ### Concatenate Strings
>
> #### Description
>
> Concatenate vectors after converting to `character`.
>
> ....
>
> #### Value
>
> A `character` vector of the concatenated values. This will be of length
>   zero if all the objects are, unless collapse is non-`NULL` in which case
>   it is a single empty string.