# What is the difference between cat and print?

Tags: r

`cat` and `print` both seem to offer a "print" functionality in R.

```
x <- 'Hello world!\n'
cat(x)
# Hello world!
print(x)
# [1] "Hello world!\n"
```

My impression is that `cat` most resembles the typical "print" function. When do I use `cat`, and when do I use `print`?

Comment: See here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-September/056972.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [The difference between concatenating character strings with paste() vs. cat()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775085/the-difference-between-concatenating-character-strings-with-paste-vs-cat)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`cat` is valid only for atomic types (logical, integer, real, complex, character) and names. It means you cannot call `cat` on a non-empty list or any type of object. In practice it simply converts arguments to characters and concatenates so you can think of something like `as.character() %>% paste()`.

`print` is a generic function so you can define a specific implementation for a certain S3 class.

```
> foo <- "foo"
> print(foo)
[1] "foo"
> attributes(foo)$class <- "foo"
> print(foo)
[1] "foo"
attr(,"class")
[1] "foo"
> print.foo <- function(x) print("This is foo")
> print(foo)
[1] "This is foo"
```

Another difference between `cat` and print is returned value. `cat` invisibly returns `NULL` while `print` returns its argument. This property of `print` makes it particularly useful when combined with pipes:

```
coefs <- lm(Sepal.Width ~  Petal.Length, iris) %>%
         print() %>%
         coefficients()
```

Most of the time what you want is `print`. `cat` can useful for things like writing a string to file:

```
sink("foobar.txt")
cat('"foo"\n')
cat('"bar"')
sink()
```

As [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843662/what-is-the-difference-between-cat-and-print/31843744#comment51610245_31843744) by [baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) you can use `cat` to redirect output directly to file. So equivalent of the above would be something like this:

```
cat('"foo"', '"bar"', file="foobar.txt", sep="\n")
```

If you want to write lines incrementally you should use `append` argument:

```
cat('"foo"', file="foobar.txt", append=TRUE)
cat('"bar"', file="foobar.txt", append=TRUE)
```

Compared to `sink` approach it is far to verbose for my taste, but it is still an option.

Comment: Also: `?cat` and `?print`

Comment: why would use sink(), when cat() has a file argument?

Comment: @baptiste It has, but if you want to write multiple lines passing both `file` and `append=TRUE` is kind of tedious.

Comment: @zero323 in that case you can open a connection for writing and leave it open until you're done.  Also, there's no reason you couldn't use `print` with `sink`.

Comment: @GSee I've never said you cannot. Still, `cat` allows you to output exact string. I know you can use `print` with `quote=FALSE` to avoid string quote and embedded quote escaping but is there any way to avoid vector representation for a character of length 1? I mean no leading `[1]` for something like `print('"foo"', quote=FALSE).`

Answer (score 14):

An essential difference between `cat` and `print` is the class of the object they return. This difference has practical consequences for what you can do with the returned object.

`print` returns a character vector:

```
> print(paste("a", 100* 1:3))
[1] "a 100" "a 200" "a 300"

> class(print(paste("a", 100* 1:3)))
[1] "a 100" "a 200" "a 300"
[1] "character"
```

`cat` returns an object of class `NULL`.

```
> cat(paste("a", 100* 1:3))
a 100 a 200 a 300

> class(cat(paste("a", 100* 1:3)))
a 100 a 200 a 300[1] "NULL"
```

In some cases, it is important to return the output as is in your console, for example when you want to copy-paste the output. In those cases, you really don't want to return a character vector. I found it a useful strategy in those cases to combine `print` and `cat`: Use `print` to create the object, use `cat` to print it to your console.

```
> output <- print(paste("a", 100* 1:3)) # use print to create the object
> cat(output) # use cat to print it *as is* to your console
a 100 a 200 a 300
```

Using `xtable` package for printing LaTeX tables in R:

```
> require(xtable)
> df <- data.frame(a = 1, č = 5) # dataframe with foreign characters
> output <- print(xtable(df), include.rownames = FALSE)
> output <- gsub("č", "c", output) # replace foreign characters before 
> # copying to LaTeX

> cat(output)
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\hline
a & c \\
\hline
1.00 & 5.00 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{table}

> print(output)
[1] "\\begin{table}[ht]\n\\centering\n\\begin{tabular}{rr}\n  
\hline\na & c    \\\\ \n  \\hline\n1.00 & 5.00 \\\\ \n   
\\hline\n\\end{tabular}\n\\end{table}\n"
```

Comment: print (often) returns the value that was given in the input. Hence: class(print(1:3)) will return an integer.