# trailing backslash gsub not working even when it is escaped

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have some html I am trying to manipulate eg:

```
imgsrc=\"Myimage1.file/img2222.jpg"
```

I want to gsub this so that I get

```
<img src="Myimage1.file/img2222.jpg"
```

I have tried

`gsub("imgsrc=\\","<img src=",mydf$V1,fixed=TRUE)`

but nothing gets replaced.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: This `cat(gsub("imgsrc=", "<img src=", x, fixed = TRUE))`?

Comment: What does cat do?

Comment: It's a `print` function. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843662/what-is-the-difference-between-cat-and-print

Comment: Thanks @Sotos. The gsub needs to be applied to a column in a datafram so I think the cat function wont work as it concatenates all the results. Also why does cat work and gsub not work in this situation?

Comment: Your `gsub()` is working. Did you assign the result to `mydf$V1`?