# Combine two outputs in a single box in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am extremely new to R.
This simple code prints two outputs:

```
ec_lineal = function(a,b){
  print(sprintf('%i x + %i = 0',a,b))
  paste(sprintf('x ='), -b / a)
}

ec_lineal(5,3)
```

```
[1] "5 x + 3 = 0"
[1] "x = -0.6"
```

When I knit the code to HTML, I get separate boxes for each of the outputs:
[image]

Is there any way to combine both outputs in a single white box?
Maybe editing the code chunk header ```` ```{r} ```` ?

I am using R 3.6.3 and the latest version of RStudio in Windows 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `cat`.

```
ec_lineal = function(a,b) {
  cat(sprintf('%i x + %i = 0',a,b), 
      paste(sprintf('x ='), -b / a),
      sep="\n")
}

ec_lineal(5,3)
# 5 x + 3 = 0
# x = -0.6
```

Comment: thank you, this will do! just to make sure, what cat() allows me to do is to print things inside one print() but on different lines, right?

Comment: @pypau Yeah, it's actually the `sep=` parameter; when you define `"\n"` (i.e. new line) it separates each string defined in `cat` with that. For the difference between `cat` and `print`  also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31843744/6574038

Comment: You're welcome, consider to [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).