# Eval parse for a JSON

Tags: json, r, parsing, eval

I am trying to automate a JSON parsing in R (I had to remove the "https:// from the URLs because I don't have enough reputation points):

```
library(Quandl)
library(jsonlite)

tmp <- 
fromJSON("www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.json?database_code=WIKI&page=2",flatten = TRUE)
```

for various numbers in `page=X`. The above code snippet executes properly. For that I am trying to use `eval(parse())` but I am doing something wrong. So I have the following:

```
text1 <- 'fromJSON("www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.json?database_code=WIKI&page='
text2 <- '",flatten = TRUE)'
and to verify that I create the string properly:
> text1
[1] "fromJSON(\www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.json?database_code=WIKI&page="
> text2
[1] "\",flatten = TRUE)"
> cat(text1,n,text2,sep="")
fromJSON("www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.json?database_code=WIKI&page=2",flatten = TRUE)
```

BUT when I try to execute:

```
koko <- eval(parse(text = cat(text1,n,text2,sep="")))
```

where `n<-2` or any other integer then the console freezes with the following error messsage:

```
?
Error in parse(text = cat(text1, n, text2, sep = "")) : 
  <stdin>:1:4: unexpected '{'
1:  D_{
       ^
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: BTW, I tried to use both "" and '' around the text1 and text2 strings but this didn't help.

Comment: `cat` won't return anything, I think you should be using `paste0` instead. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12775193/5977215)

Comment: Why are using `eval(parse())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of [the difference between paste and cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775085/the-difference-between-concatenating-character-strings-with-paste-vs-cat)

`cat` will just print to the screen, it won't return anything. To create a string you should use `paste` or `paste0`.

For example, consider

```
concat <- cat(text1, n, text2)
p <- paste0(text1, n, text2)
```

Even when running `concat <- cat(text1, n, text2)`, it prints the output to the console, and `concat` is empty/NULL

The **solution** is to use `paste0` to create the string expression

```
text1 <- 'fromJSON("http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.json?database_code=WIKI&page='
text2 <- '",flatten = TRUE)'
n <- 2
koko <- eval(parse(text = (paste0(text1, n, text2))))
```

Also, you don't **need** to use `eval`, you can use `paste0` directly

```
text1 <- 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets.json?database_code=WIKI&page='
n <- 2

koko <- fromJSON(paste0(text1, n), flatten=TRUE)
```