# Printing a timestamp from paste

Tags: r

I want a little helper to prepend a timestamp for each debug statement. I'm not looking to use a logger library. Here is the attempt:

```
tp = function(...) {
  ts = format(Sys.time(), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")
  m = paste('[',ts,']',str(...))
  print(m)
}
```

When invoking the helper `tp` to print the columns of a `data.frame` :

```
 tp(names(df))
```

The intended output is this:

```
[ 04.03.2020 19:35:00.345 ]  country state day dt confirmed recovered deaths
```

But the actual output is:

```
 chr [1:7] "country" "state" "day" "dt" "confirmed" "recovered" "deaths"
[1] "[ 04.03.2020 19:35:00.345 ] "
```

Note that I added

```
 str(...)
```

because otherwise the output is *one line per column element*. Instead the output should keep the printing on one line: maybe via joining the collection items some way?  I could use some help on cleaning this up.

Comment: has the `r` tag and last i checked it ran in the `r` interpreter ;)

Comment: ah I typo'ed the `df.names` fixing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably actually want `cat`, not `print`.

Then you could define:

```
tp = function(...) {
  cat(format(Sys.time(), "[ %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS ]"), ...)
  return(invisible())
}

tp(names(df))
# [ 05.03.2020 12:03:13.015595 ] country state day
```

Notice the lack of `[1] "..."`

FWIW R has `date()` built in which has a different format but is more concise:

```
cat(date())
# Thu Mar  5 04:04:37 2020
```

Or, if you don't need subsecond accuracy and are fine with ISO formatting, `format = '[ %F %T ]'` is also more concise.

You might also consider using `%z` and/or the `tz` argument to `format.POSIXct` to convey the system time zone in your log as well.

Comment: thx i had just inquired about removing the extra fanfare; that takes care of it

Comment: did you try it out? I see a `NULL` at the end  `4.03.2020 20:13:05.224]  country state day dt confirmed recovered deathsNULL`

Comment: @javadba you might check https://stackoverflow.com/q/31843662/3576984 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/12775085/3576984 for some more details about `cat` vs `print`. In sum, `cat` is ideal for logging (straight to `stdout`), `print` is more about understanding/displaying structures in R.

Comment: re `NULL` my bad I did not replace `print` with `return`. It works as you show.

Comment: yep -- the return value of `cat` is `NULL` (ditto for `invisible()`) -- see `x=cat(1, 2, 3); print(x)`. You may want to add a `cat('\n')` to force carriage return as well, or put `'\n'` after `...`.

Comment: thx.  you'll be hearing from novice-R-me more .. well actually .. _v_  soon

Answer (score 3):

You need to paste together the ellipsis arguments into a single string.

```r
tp = function(...) {
  ts = format(Sys.time(), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")
  m = paste('[', ts, ']', paste(..., collapse = " "))
  print(m)
}

df <- data.frame("country" = NA,
                 "state" = NA,
                 "day" = NA)

tp(names(df))
#> [1] "[ 05.03.2020 08:10:58 ] country state day"
```

Comment: ah ya - frequently see people define `paste0 = function (...) paste(...,collapse='')`. In this case i might collapse with a `,`

Comment: is it possible to omit the double parens around the output -which now looks like `[1] "[ 04.03.2020 20:08:11.736 ] country state day dt confirmed recovered deaths"` when run in the `REPL`

Comment: In that case, you'd want `cat` as Michael answered below.

Comment: i retained the upvote here but accepted Michael's as you suggest

Comment: Yeah, it's a better answer ha!