# R: Find length of bigz vector without using the length function

Tags: r, optimization, vector, biginteger, gmp

In `R`, to find the length of a vector (`bigz` or not), one typically uses the `length` function. E.g.

```
NonBigZ <- 1:10

NonBigZ
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

length(NonBigZ)
[1] 10
```

However, using the `gmp` package, if you declare a `bigz` vector, the length of the vector is returned automatically. E.g.

```
BigZ <- as.bigz(1:10)

BigZ
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 10:  ## <<-- length given here
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

## This seems redundant as it is already given above
length(BigZ)
[1] 10
```

I would like to retrieve that information without making the extra call to `length`.  I know `length` is lightning fast, but it could save a pretty decent chunk of time if you could avoid calling it. Observe:

```
system.time(sapply(1:10^6, function(x) length(BigZ)))
user  system elapsed 
7.81    0.00    7.84
```

I have tried `attributes(BigZ)` as well as `str(BigZ)` to no avail. I have read the [gmp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/gmp.pdf) documentation as well, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `gmp:::print.bigz`, also, calculates `length` using `gmp:::length.bigz`. It seems that `length.bigz` is not just an attribute access function like `length` -- e.g. see `ns = c(1, 10, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1e3, 5e3, 1e4); timings = sapply(ns, function(n) { x = as.bigz(seq_len(n)); summary(microbenchmark(length(x), unit = "ms"))$median }); plot(ns, timings)`. I guess, it might be worth to save the "length" as an attribute when creating a "bigz".

Comment: Rather than putting your answer into your question (and leaving the question looking unresolved), you should just answer your own question.

Comment: @Gregor, I was hesitant about posting as an answer as I wasn't sure if my answer was thorough enough. Anywho, I have taken your suggestion.

Comment: It seems to answer your question, so I think it's better as an answer than as a question. If someone comes along with a better answer you can always upvote/accept that one. I believe there's a 48 hour wait period on accepting your own answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alexis_laz pointed out in the comments, `gmp::print.bigz` already calculates the length but doesn't return it in any usable format. I did some digging into the `gmp` source code and found this:

```
print.bigz <- function(x, quote = FALSE, initLine = is.null(modulus(x)), ...)
{
  if((n <- length(x)) > 0) {
    if(initLine) {
      cat("Big Integer ('bigz') ")
      kind <- if(isM <- !is.null(nr <- attr(x, "nrow")))
        sprintf("%d x %d matrix", nr, n/nr)
      else if(n > 1) sprintf("object of length %d", n) else ""
      cat(kind,":\n", sep="")
    }
    print(as.character(x), quote = quote, ...)
  }
  else
    cat("bigz(0)\n")
  invisible(x)
}
```

As you can see, it uses the `cat` function to return your `bigz` object. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1405571/4408538) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406170/4408538), it is possible to retrieve the requested information, however, it isn't nearly as efficient as simply calling `length`.  Below is a very crude function for obtaining the length.

```
BigZLength <- function(x) {
    b <- capture.output(x)
    a <- strsplit(b[1], split=" ")[[1]][7]
    if (!is.na(a)) {as.integer(substr(a,1,nchar(a)-1))} else {1L}
}

system.time(sapply(1:10^5, function(x) length(BigZ)))
 user  system elapsed 
0.67    0.00    0.67 

system.time(sapply(1:10^5, function(x) BigZLength(BigZ)))
 user  system elapsed 
24.57    0.01   24.71
```

I'm sure you could write a more efficient function using regular expressions (or something else), however, I don't believe it will be as efficient as simply calling `length`. In fact, simply getting the output of `cat` takes most of the time in the above code.

```
system.time(sapply(1:10^5, function(x) capture.output(BigZ)))
 user  system elapsed 
20.00    0.00   20.03
```

## A note about fetching the source code above

If you are familiar with `R` you know that you can view the source code of a given function by simply typing the function in the console and printing it like so:

```
numbers::nextPrime
function (n) 
{
    if (n <= 1) 
        n <- 1
    else n <- floor(n)
    n <- n + 1
    d1 <- max(3, round(log(n)))
    P <- Primes(n, n + d1)
    while (length(P) == 0) {
        n <- n + d1 + 1
        P <- Primes(n, n + d1)
    }
    return(as.numeric(min(P)))
}
<environment: namespace:numbers>
```

However, sometimes this is not possible. For example with `gmp::print.bigz` we obtain:

```
gmp::print.bigz
Error: 'print.bigz' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gmp'
```

Enter Joshua Ulrich’s awesome [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/4408538) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226817/4408538). Using the code he suggests below, you can download the source code of any package and unpack it in one line.

```
untar(download.packages(pkgs = "gmp",
                        destdir = ".",
                        type = "source")[,2])
```

This creates a folder in your directory with all of the compiled code.  The above source code was found in the `.\gmp\R\biginteger.R` file.