# save extracted (using cat) text in a variable in R

Tags: r

I am using following code which extracts the text between quotation in R. It works fine, the only problem is that it does not save the extracted text in a variable. 
What am I missing here? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
var2 <- cat(sub('.*"(.*)".*', "\\1", var1))
var2
```

Comment: Remove the `cat` function. `cat` returns NULL. See `?cat`. If you really want to print out the result, wrap the sucker in `(...)` like this: `(var2 <- sub('.*"(.*)".*', "\\1", var1))`.

Comment: That's what I initially thought but removing cat does not work as it did not extract text with the quotation. As soon I as I add cat it does extract the text between quotation.

Comment: I am skeptical of this claim as I have never experienced this. Please provide an example of var1 that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @lmo I will attach the example shortly, thanks!

Comment: @lmo value of var1 is extracted from a fifth matrix column and it shows as this two lines:
 V5
“a5 \ “lb1 : c2 c4 c1 \””

When I use sub it shows me value as two lines:
 V5
“lb1: c2 c4 c1”
And when I use  cat with sub it shows value as “lb1: c2 c4 c1”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `capture.output` in this case.

```
var2 <- capture.output(cat(sub('.*"(.*)".*', "\\1", var1)))
var2
```

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405571/how-to-assign-output-of-cat-to-an-object).

Comment: Thank you, Barbara, This answers my question.